# Shorten C# condition

Tags: c#, syntax, conditional-statements

Given the following condition:

```
bool roundUp = (useSharps && lowerHalf) || (!useSharps && !lowerHalf);
//which means roundUp will be false if useSharps but !lowerHalf,
//or if !useSharps but lowerHalf
```

Is there a shorter way to determine `roundUp`?

Here are the possible options:

```
          |      useSharps     |     !useSharps     |
          |lowerHalf|!lowerHalf|lowerHalf|!lowerHalf|
          -------------------------------------------
   roundUp|    V    |     X    |    X    |     V    |
  !roundUp|    X    |     V    |    V    |     X    |
          -------------------------------------------

          V = true, X = false
```

**Update:**
Maybe I was wrong with my code. The final result I'm looking for is what's in the table.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you want your variables `useSharps` and `lowerHalf` to be equivalent (either both false or both true), you can just check for equality:

```
var roundUp = useSharps == lowerHalf;
```

**EDIT**

If I interpret your table correctly, your code fits it perfectly (as well as the shortened version in my answer). The table itself could be simplified to this:

```
lowerHalf | useSharps | roundUp
--------------------------------
    0     |     0     |    1
    0     |     1     |    0
    1     |     0     |    0
    1     |     1     |    1
```

Comment: Edited my answer, I think your code and table match perfectly. Please explain if I got something mixed up though.

Answer (score 2):

If you need one value `true` and another `false`, you could use:

```
var roundUp = useSharps == !lowerHalf;
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are easier, but I just want to point out another way.
You can check if 2 boolean variables have different values by using the xor operator.

```
useSharps ^ lowerHalf
```

If this returns true, they have different values, if false, they have the same value.

Comment: Good point but then I have to recheck whether they're true or not.

Comment: Personally, I prefer to use `!=` when checking if two boolean values are inequal, as I feel that being more obvious to what it does. The XOR `^` operator is still very useful for bit-operations i.e. on byte values.

Comment: @Chips_100 question is not preference, I prefer to look at it on whether it works or not. I'd prefer this answer if it'd work.

Comment: @Shimmy As both versions do actually work, the choice is matter of preference. You could use this version in your actual code as `bool roundUp = !(useSharps ^ lowerHalf);`

Comment: @Chips_100. You're right. but I'll stick to `useSharps == lowerHalf` which is obviously shorter.

Comment: I would prefer that too in this case, actually. Its meaning is more clear. I was just showing an alternative. (maybe it's useful in some cases)